# ¿Como convierto el numero decimal 1.5 a binario 1.1 in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Trato de hacer:

```
a=1.5
puts a.to_s(2)
```

Pero no funciona

Alguna sugerencia por favor ya que no se ni el nombre de los digitos que van despues del punto que yo conozco por decimales pero no creo que sea el caso

Answer (score 0):

Con Ruby no puedes convertir números con decimales (i.e. de clase `Float`) a binario con `to_s`, pues ese método no existe an la clase `Float`.

Sin embargo puedes crear un método para hacerlo, por ejemplo:

```
def float_to_binary(float)
  int, dec = float.divmod(1)
  bin = "#{int.to_s(2)}."

  while dec > 0
    int, dec = (dec * 2).divmod(1)
    bin << int.to_s
  end

  bin
end
```

Prueba:

```
a = 1.5

float_to_binary(a)
#=> "1.1"
```

El método probablemente se pueda optimizar un poco, pero este código es funcional y consigue el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar esta gema:  https://rubygems.org/gems/binary

Con ella puedes hacer algo como esto:

2018.to_b

y te devuelve "11111100010"

Aquí está la documentación:  https://github.com/almishkawi/binary